# Radio button on shiny app error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have made a shiny code that would take input from user and save answer in x=excel file. When I add the radio button code line(commented) in question list I get error. Why is the error and what can be done to resolve it?

```
install.packages("devtools")
install.packages("digest")
install.packages("shiny")
devtools::install_github("daattali/shinyforms")
library(shiny)
library(shinyforms)

questions <- list(
  list(id = "name", type = "text", title = "Name", mandatory = TRUE),
  list(id = "age", type = "numeric", title = "Age", mandatory = TRUE),
  list(id = "Income", title = "Your average annual income from all sources before tax (e.g. Pension, employment, investments, etc.) is", type = "text", mandatory = TRUE),
  list(id = "saving", type = "text", title = "You regularly save the following percentage of your income for special expenditures, such as education, mortgage lump sum repayments, retirement, etc", mandatory = TRUE),
  list(id = "continue", title = "You expect your current income level (at a minimum) to continue for the:", type = "text", mandatory = TRUE),
  list(id = "status", type = "text", title = "You would describe your financial situation as being:", mandatory = TRUE),
#radioButtons("gender", label = ("select the Gender"),choices = list("Male" = 1, "Female" = 2),selected = 1),
  list(id = "correct", type = "checkbox", title = "I have given correct answers")
   )
formInfo <- list(
  id = "basicinfo",
  questions = questions,

  storage = list(
    # Right now, only flat file storage is supported
    type = STORAGE_TYPES$FLATFILE,
    # The path where responses are stored
    path = "D:\\CP\\responses\\"
  )
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  #titlePanel("Registation Form"),
  formUI(formInfo)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  formServer(formInfo)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Error: I get the below error when I run the ui <- fluidPage

Error in if (question$id %in% fieldsMandatory) { :    argument is of
length zero

Comment: "Supported question types: text, numeric, checkbox" from the github

Comment: Didn't you do a mistake in `question$id` instead of `questions$id`?

Comment: You should use `radioButton` on the `ui` or put it in `output$something` with `?renderUI`. Though it seems that there is no need to render it from server, as you don't use any variables/data from server in it.